# Does the textgrid widget in go fyne editable?

Tags: go, fyne

I'm trying to build a simple code editor with fyne, and I saw in the doc the widget TextGrid, so I tried to use it, but when I run the code I can't modify the text.

here is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Text Editor")
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(1400, 1000))
    text := widget.NewTextGrid()
    w.SetContent(text)
    w.ShowAndRun()

}
```

if I can't modify it, I don't see the purpose of this widget, is there a way to make it modifiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextGrid` component is something more developer focused for building more complex components (like a terminal or code editor).
For a ready-to-use text editor use `widget.NewMultiLineEditor()`.

You can see a more complete example at https://github.com/fyne-io/examples/blob/develop/textedit/ui.go.

Comment: Do you have an example of the use of `TextGrid` ? because I'm trying to build a code editor.

Comment: Yes, you can see how we built a full terminal app. The main (re-usable) component is at https://github.com/fyne-io/terminal/blob/master/term.go